# How to generate an "app-specific password" with Team Account in order to notarize app?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, apple-developer, electron-notarize

I am trying to notarize an Electron app using `electron-builder`and [electron-notarize](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize). The docs state that an app specific password is needed and provides this link: [Using app-specific passwords](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397).

The problem is that link is about generating "app-specific passwords" for ***personal*** Apple ID accounts – not Apple Developer accounts. And I am part of a team and there is no place (e.g. a "Security" panel) in either my personal ADC account nor the parts of team account I have access too (where I have admin privileges).

I've tried all combinations I can think of for `APPLEID` and `APPLEIDPASS`when trying to notarize: my personal Apple ID & password, the team's Apple ID & password, "app-specfic passwords" I created in my personal account.

It's can't be this hard. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve my notarization issues. I don't know if this is "the right way" but it worked, so here is what I did – maybe it will save someone the time and frustration I went through.

**Context:** I am a contractor with "Admin" privileges on my client's Apple Developer account, along with my having a personal ADC account. As noted in my question, the `Electron Builder` docs state that an "app-specific password" is needed and links to an Apple doc about how to generate one. However, that link is or seems to be about generating a specific password to use with a 3rd party app like "Twitter" – so that one's personal Apple ID password is protected. At least that is the way I read it. There is no place within my personal ADC account or the Team account where such a password can be generated. So I generated a password in my personal ADC account.

This post from [Electron Builder issues](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize/issues/25#issuecomment-569956847) introduced an additional property to pass to `notarize`: the "ProviderShortname". As noted in the post, this can be accessed through:

```
xcrun altool --list-providers -u <personal APPLE ID> -p <app-specific pw generated within that acct>
```

This gives a list of memberships. I then used the Team ID as the value for "ascProvider" in the code below:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { notarize } = require('electron-notarize');

exports.default = async function notarizing(context) {
  const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = context;  
  if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
    return;
  }

  const appName = context.packager.appInfo.productFilename;

  return await notarize({
    appBundleId: 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz',
    appPath: `${appOutDir}/${appName}.app`,
    appleId: process.env.APPLEID,
    appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLEIDPASS,
    ascProvider: process.env.ASCPROVIDER
  });
};
```

The app successfully notarized (and Apple sends a confirmation email) and the rest of the packaging proceeded. I also ran into some issues with creating the `dmg` after the notarization receipt had been "stapled" to the app (which didn't occur prior to my attempts to notarize the app). These issues had to do with missing a required "message" and "lang" code (in my case "en-us"). I solved it by making the additions to the example `Electron Builder" provides as show below.

Again, I do not know if this is the "right way" to handle all of this – but it worked. I suppose that if one is an individual developer rather than part of a team, the boilerplate Electron Builder instructions work.

```
{
  "languageName": "English",
  "lang": "en-us",
  "agree": "Agree",
  "disagree": "Disagree",
  "print": "Print",
  "save": "Save",
  "description": "",
  "message": "If you agree with the terms of this license, press 'Agree' to install the software.  If you do not agree, press 'Disagree'"
}
```